# Coding issue with front web page - HTML/CSS Coded

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I just finished building a site called https://services.codexcentre.com, and able to duplicate the page fine on my PC.

But when I provide my friend to review the site, she inform me on the first page down below where the 4 boxes are located it looks squeezed together - this only shows on mobile (PC it looks fine.)

When I duplicate the problem on my phone, I find the same issue and not sure why it's doing this. I have the code pasted below to how this was structured. To have an idea, this is a wordpress site and I custom coded this section due to problems with the wordpress column structure.

Any feedback is appreciated.

```
<style>

    .gallery_container{
        max-width: 1200px;
        padding: 30px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }

    #shop_column{
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 15px;
    }

    #shop_page{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    #shop_image{
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 750px;
        height: 345px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }


</style>



<div class="gallery_container">
    <div id="shop_column">
        <a href="http://services.codexcentre.com/new-build/">
            <img id="shop_image" src="imgs/home01.jpg">
        </a>
        <p id="shop_page">New Build</p>
        <a href="http://services.codexcentre.com/dining-remodel/">
            <img id="shop_image" src="imgs/dining01.jpeg">
        </a>
        <p id="shop_page">Living Room Remodel</p>
    </div>
    <div id="shop_column">
        <a href="http://services.codexcentre.com/kitchen-remodel/">
            <img id="shop_image" src="imgs/kitchen01.jpg">
        </a>
        <p id="shop_page">Kitchen Remodel</p>
        <a href="http://services.codexcentre.com/bathroom-remodel/">
            <img id="shop_image" src="imgs/bathroom01.jpg"> 
        </a>
        <p id="shop_page">Bathroom Remodel</p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] (and get a badge). Your question should include the source code causing the issue in the question. External links are not helpful and may disappear in the future, meaning others cannot benefit from your fine question in the future. Taking the tour and reading about [ask] a good question in the [help] center will provide all the information you need. When you say _looks fine on PC but not on mobile_ you do not explain what the problem is and how, exactly, you expect it to look

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting should happen?

As I can see, you have two problems depending what you want.

1. You get two columns in mobile but want one. Fix by adding media-query to one column in mobile.
2. Images get stretched since you have fixed values.

Comment: May sound arrogant, but I expected it to review the same on mobile as it did on pc. That's why I never thought of it till I was told by my friend when she review the site on mobile it was squeezed.

Answer (score 0):

You have To make your website responsive so that it look attractive in all the devices.

```
@media(Max-width:345px){#shop_image{width:250px}}
```

And change other aspects also according to the width of device